# SASS - iniciante (dúvida pequena)

Tags: sass

Olá!
Estou aprendendo SASS e me deparei com um problema que era pra ser simples,. heehehe.

Isso não está compilando:

```css
$purple: #9b0aa8;

#fofo{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background: $purple;
}

#fofo:hover{
  @include transform(translateY(50%), scale(0.5));
}
```

```html
<div id="fofo"></div>
```

Ele apresenta prblema na linha:

```
`@include transform(translateY(50%), scale(0.5));'
```

dizendo:

```
  stdin 10:3  root stylesheet on line 10 at column 3
```

Alguma ideia? parece tudo certo pra mim. =//

Comment: Jovem teste sem essa vírgula entre translateY(50%), scale(0.5), assim  ` @include transform(translateY(50%) scale(0.5))` e veja se compila. Se der certo me fale que eu publico como resposta ok :)

Comment: Não deu. =/
Eu tinha feito inicialmente sem.
Valeu!

Comment: Estou usando o https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: Eita, agora deu: Undefined mixin.
  stdin 10:3  root stylesheet on line 10 at column 3

Comment: Da uma olhada como o código que eu coloquei na resposta, compilou sem erros!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que primeiramente vc deve criar o seu @mixin, e depois fazer o @include como vc pode consultar no guia: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Dessa forma:

```
$purple: #9b0aa8;

@mixin transform($property, $propertyx) {
  transform: $property, $propertyx;
}

#fofo{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background: $purple;
}

#fofo:hover{
  @include transform(rotate(30deg), scale(0.5));
}
```

Vc pode testar aqui que vc vai ver que vai compilar direitinho https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: Aaah tá, pelo tutorial que eu estava seguindo não parecia necessário criar o mixin. Tá aí, obrigado!

Comment: @RPGDeividPacheco eu não sou especialista em SCSS rss, pode ser que tenha outra forma, mas o que eu posso garantir é que da forma que eu fiz não vai dar erro... mas pode não ser a melhor forma de fazer rss. Pelo Guia me pareceu que é para fazer assim...